# cookies validation using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium. Actually I am working on some cookie validation project, which requires me to manually check the cookies present before and after clicking on some consent link in multiple browsers (Firefox, ie, chrome, safari).

Previously in the phase 1 project I ran a qtp script to treat the firefox as a window object and capture screenshots, but that is quite troublesome if the resolution changes or any minor look-n-feel changes. Also it is quite difficult to manage and it works on firefox only and I needed to write the same script again for chrome and safari. Apart from this since QTP is licensed product and currently we are using seat license so I can't run it on multiple machines to speed up execution.

So I thought moving to Selenium. As of now my requirement is:

```
1. open the page - take the screenshot once page loaded.
2. check the cookies using firebug or any other way  - take the screenshot
3. click the link to close the consent - take screenshot once consent closed.
4. refresh the page and again check the cookies using firebug - take screenshot
```

So I done some research on selenium and found that I can validate the cookies using verifyCookie but still I need screenshot of firebug window for cookies. So I got stuck here.

please help me out here..

I found some possible way to do this on Firefox but now I was looking forward for something similar for Chrome if that possible. Thanks

Comment: Actually this kind of be weird but I was thinking if similar kind of code can be prepared for chrome as there isn't the kind of firebug available for chrome that I am using in Firefox.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some solution

```
public class Selenium1st {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe");
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

        String domain = "extensions.firebug.";
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
        firefoxProfile.addExtension(new File("E:\\softs\\selenium-2.29.0\\firebug\\firebug-1.11.2-fx.xpi"));
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(domain + "currentVersion", "1.11.2");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.cookies.enableSites", true);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation", "on");

        firefoxProfile.setPreference(domain + "framePosition", "bottom");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(domain + "defaultPanelName", "cookies");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");
        query.sendKeys("\n");
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(new Dimension(1024, 768)));

        File path = new File("E:\\abc");//Path to your file
        if(path.getName().indexOf(".jpg") == -1){
            path = new File(path.getPath() + ".jpg");
        }       
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", path);                
    }

}
```

might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium cannot interact with firefox extensions, or the browser in the way you want it to.

What you can do is collect a list of cookies on the page by doing:

```
driver.manage().getCookies()
```

This will give you a list of all cookies that are visible to Selenium. Please note that this is the same as the cookies that are visible in the JavaScript console (Not all cookies are visible via JavaScript, for example cookies set with the HTTPOnly attribute) using:

```
document.cookie
```

I would suggest you use getCookies() to programatically validate the cookies.

Comment: actually Ardesco, cookie validation is not a problem, actually the problem is to capture the screenshot of all the loaded cookies. Actually I need those screenshots to be uploaded in quality center.

Comment: Selenium cannot open firebug and take a screenshot of the cookie panel.  I guess I'm stuggling to understand why it *has* to be a screenshot.  Why isn't getting your automated test to print out the list of known cookies and upload that to quality center good enough?

Comment: ok.. actually that screenshot is necessary to get it uploaded in the qc. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium IDE if you want to take screenshot of the page use `captureEntirePageScreenshot` command

```
   captureEntirePageScreenshot | D:\\test.png | 

     D:\\test.png - path of file where you want to save the file
```